# When handling errors in code, is it acceptable to just return a single "error" value through the call chain back to the entry point?

Tags: design-patterns, error-handling, language-agnostic

I am running into a few instances in my code where valid user input is invalid for the operation being performed (Such as entering a schedule adherence entry for an employee that has no schedule because they were in training). This is an allowed action, but understandably creates an error down the road when calculating schedule adherence reports. In this example an error will be thrown when it finds no schedule for that employee at the time of the adherence entry.

In this case I would normally return an object that encapsulates some basic data on the entry and the schedule. If an error such as this occurs I return `-1`, and all proceeding methods just check for a `-1`, if it's found then they also return `-1` instead of performing their usual actions. all the way back up to the start of the call chain where no more returns are expected and no final action is taken on a `-1` value.

Is this an appropriate pattern to handle errors in your code? If not, what would be the preferable way to handle these?

Comment: I don't think this question is language-agnostic. The answer will depend on  the error-handling mechanisms that your language supports. Furthermore, many languages support more than one programming paradigm, so the answer will depend on which of those paradigms you are following. As an example, error handling in Java differs between the  object-oriented and functional paradigms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one way to do it, but there are downsides:

- you need each function along the way to handle the error
- you lack any context when handling the error (you do not know why the error occured in the calling functions)

A better approach is using the exception/try-catch mechanisms that most languages have. It allows you to handle the error in the function that you want (even at the top if you want), and adds context. It's also more scalable, robust and readable (everyone reading the code understand what an exception is).

Comment: Definitely agree with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DevShark's answer : for scalability/readability/robustness you need to separate the erroneous value from its context.

Here by returning -1 you encode the error context in the value which can be fine as long as the error is caught "soon".

**What if other error contexts should be retrieved?**

You'll have to "bind" another forbidden value (-2, -3, ...)
You'll end with a duplication of error logic handling at many places

```
if( error == -1 )
   // treat exception -1 here
if( error == -2 )
   // treat exception -2 + alert top component
   return error
else 
   // error is undefined
   return error;
```

**What if -1 becomes an acceptable value along the road?**

You'll then have to translate the error into something else which can be misleading.

**What to do?**

As Devshark stated the try/catch exception is fine and actually designed for handling error-cases ; however depending on your application constraint (real-time, ...) or programming field (embedded, ...) it would be simpler/lighter to implement this with a pairing technique such as :

```
// ErrorType could be an enum describing the context
// ValueType could be what you want from scalar type to pointer to more complex structures
std::pair<ErrorType, ValueType>

// For instance a typical function returning bool error and int value
std::pair<bool, int> foo( ) 
{
   std::pair<bool, int> res;

   // handle your task - get the new value
   int newVal = foo2();

   if( errorOccurs ) 
   {
      res.first = false; // flag indicating error
      res.second = -1; // value can be made invalid or not
   } else {
      res.first = true;
      res.second = newVal;
   }

   return res;
```

}

Comment: Definitely agree, I recently started programming in a different language, and didn't even try and see if it had try catch blocks like C#.